# Getting Collection Names Of Products in Shopify

Tags: shopify

In Shopify how do I fetch names of custom collection that a particular product belongs to ?

Like for example to get ***SKU*** I can use `{{ line_item.sku }}` or to get ***Price*** I can use `{{ line_item.line_price` }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [API docs](http://api.shopify.com/customcollection.html#index), to list all custom collections for a certain product_id:

```
GET /admin/custom_collections.json?product_id=632910392
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{
  "custom_collections": [
    {
      "body_html": "<p>The best selling ipod ever</p>",
      "handle": "ipods",
      "id": 841564295,
      "published_at": "2008-02-01T19:00:00-05:00",
      "sort_order": "manual",
      "template_suffix": null,
      "title": "IPods",
      "updated_at": "2008-02-01T19:00:00-05:00",
      "image": {
        "created_at": "2012-12-11T12:01:29-05:00",
        "src": "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0006/9093/3842/collections/ipod_nano_8gb.jpg?0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The API docs link no longer points to the appropriate place; the new URL is [here](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customcollection#index)